# Is it useful to select none with D3, and how?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, css-selectors

I want a call to `d3.selectAll` to return nothing. It seems like this should be a common pattern, something like -

```
d3.selectAll(false) // maybe?
.data([10,20,30])
.enter()
// ... manipulate
```

Which would require a selector returning nothing. In particular this seems to be an issue in [this implementation of a donut chart](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887193) -

```
var g = svg.selectAll(".arc")
  .data(pie(data))
.enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "arc");
```

This is evil because "arc" is a global class that could be used somewhere else in the webpage and this is library code. Yet there's no good way to articulate the thing we're trying to select. The arc class? This is obviously a kludgey use of class and has this side effect. I can't say "arc" because they're just paths which are too general, although [that's what's used in this example, only with circles](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/join/).

So seems to be a hanging point.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what good would a `selectAll` be if it returned no elements? Not seeing the point.

Comment: @Justin so you can enter new elements.

Comment: Just select elements that don't exist yet as in pretty much all the examples.

Comment: @AAA - It looks like Lars is right: http://bost.ocks.org/mike/join/

Comment: @LarsKotthoff doesn't cut it, see edit

Comment: @AAA What you would usually do is append a new `g` element and then do everything below that, e.g. `var g = svg.append("g"); g.selectAll(...)`. If you look at the reusable components of D3 (e.g. the axis) you'll see that they are meant to be called on a `g` element that should be empty. This effectively achieves a form of namespacing where issues like the one you mention are not relevant.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff what goes in the `g.seletAll(...)`? That may be what I don't understand.

Comment: It is entirely possible to construct a selector that will logically match nothing (browser bugs notwithstanding). This is hilariously easy using `:not()` as you can just tell a selector to negate itself: `*|*:not(*|*)` or `x:not(x)`. There are other ways without using negation as well, for example `*+:first-child` or `:last-child+*`. Not posting as an answer though since I don't have enough experience with D3 to judge whether this is really an XY problem after all.

Comment: @AAA You would usually select the elements you want to append in the enter selection, but in principle it doesn't matter. My point is that when you do that you *know* what elements are in that subtree of the DOM (none to start with) and you don't have any issues with inadvertently selecting elements you didn't want to select.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're misinterpreting the reason you sometimes select non-existent elements with d3.

In d3's data join paradigm, you select the elements you want to bind data to. If those elements don't exist yet, d3 knows to place them in the Enter selection so you can address them using `.enter()`. The [article](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/join/) linked in your question is the best explanation of this. I urge you to go over it again.

To be more concrete, let's look at the donut chart visualization you mentioned:

```
var g = svg.selectAll(".arc")
    .data(pie(data))
  .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "arc");
```

Why do we select `.arc` even though it doesn't exist yet?

Some background: d3 is a functional approach to programming, which means we don't often tell it *how* to do things but rather *what* we want done. We're asking d3 to bind our data (in this case whatever `pie(data)` returns) to the `.arc` elements in the DOM. That is, we want to correlate, or "bind", each piece of data in an array to each DOM element. We then get back three selections: Enter, Update, and Exit.

The *Enter* selection contains placeholders for all the elements that exist in the data but don't yet have corresponding DOM elements. This selection is usually used in conjunction with `.append()` to create the new DOM nodes.

The *Update* selection contains the actual DOM elements that already exist, but which will now be bound to the new data.

The *Exit* selection contains the DOM elements that do not have corresponding data in our new data set. Those are often `.remove()`ed.

Going back to the arc example, the first time this code is run there are no `.arc` elements in the DOM. So we get an Enter selection that contains what is effectively placeholders for the new data. We then act on these placeholders by appending a bunch of new elements, and giving them the class `.arc` so that *next time* we run this code, say when we get new data, they'll be found.

The way this code is structured, if we provide new data a second time having the same length, the Enter selection will be empty and the Update selection will be full. But it won't contain placeholders, instead it'll contain the DOM elements we added the first time.

This is all to say that the use case of selecting nothing is only common insofar as we're looking to bind new data to not-yet existing elements. But we're not selecting nothing *per se*, rather we're binding new data to soon to be created DOM elements.

On a side note, selecting `.arc` may not be "evil" since we're saying `svg.selectAll()`. That is, only select `.arc` elements that are children of `svg`, thus localizing our selection.

Comment: evil because there's a stylesheet that this svg has no awareness of in an application called "Applied Real Conversions" that has the rule ".arc { display: none; } " half the time.